# why invalid hook call in react app (with react-router-dom)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i want to play around a react app and the first file is making trouble by using a function from react-router-dom. The Docs said: maybe mismatching react versions or using a class component.

here is my parent App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const App = () => {
  let id = useParams();
  console.log(id);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.childNodes[1].style.display='none'
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>RouterComponents and screens</div>
  )
}
```

Nothing big in here but i get the error `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...`

here are my questions:

1. This is a function component? (Sure, it is)
2. why useEffect works and useParams not?
3. have all imported components to be function components now or could it mixed?
4. is there a way to check if different react versions are used?

Thx for your help and time to bring me up lights in the dark react components.

edit, add error trace:

```
at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476)
at useContext (react.development.js:1484)
at useParams (react-router.js:734)
at App (App.js:18)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
```

edit 2, my app.js webpack file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './js/screens/app/App'
const $ = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap');
import 'nanoscroller'
import './fontawesome/css/all.min.css'
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import './styles/theme.css';
import './styles/custom.css';  
import './js/theme'
import './js/theme.init'

ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the component throwing the warning? Can you post, in your question, the actual message?

Comment: when i delete these 2 rows it works. i update the question... one moment

Comment: I see no issue here, can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could examine live?

Comment: Sure. https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-wilson-jodl2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1 Here i can see only the error match of undefined whats correct error message. So for now its possible that in my webpack app.js file i the error. i added it above

Comment: React router context is not available. Wrap the App in a Router component from react router dom package.

Comment: You are not rendering anything into a `Router` so there is no routing context. Lol, Ajeet, just 30s ahead of me today.

Comment: i updated the sandbox as the same as my local files.. it works without errors. no idea whats wrong here

Comment: In that case, just delete node_modules folder and yarn.lock or package-lock.json file and reinstall the deps. (Be careful don't delete any useful file).

Comment: Try to ensure you've killed any running dev server processes and that you've fully quit before restarting.

Comment: i deleted node_modules, and restart all and the same error (without) node_modules. maybe there is a global react mismatch as described...

Comment: OK Solved. Complete reinstallation solved this issue. cannot say what was wrong in here